# Spring: Cancel a @Scheduled annotated task

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I am running a Spring Boot app, and trying to get two jobs running with a specific delay using the `@Scheduled` annotation.

I would like to cancel these jobs programmatically on a particular condition. What's the recommended way of doing this? Following is the configuration of my app:

**Main.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {

  static LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.now();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
    app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
    app.run(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
  }

}
```

**Job1.java**

```
@Component
public class Job1 {

  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Job 1 running");
  }

}
```

**Job2.java**

```
@Component
public class Job1 {

  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Job 2 running");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to schedule your tasks via one of the implementations of `Spring TaskScheduler` interface, for example a [TimerManagerTaskScheduler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/commonj/TimerManagerTaskScheduler.html) or [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html), getting  [ScheduledFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) objects.

```
public interface TaskScheduler {

    ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger);

    ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Date startTime);

    ScheduledFuture scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, Date startTime, long period);

    ScheduledFuture scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, long period);

    ScheduledFuture scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, Date startTime, long delay);

    ScheduledFuture scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, long delay);

}
```

`ScheduledFuture` object provides method to cancel the task (ScheduledFuture.cancel())

Answer (score 0):

The schedule method has a scheduled future. get a handle to this future in your method and then you can call cancel on it to cancel the job
you can refer [Spring-Boot stop Scheduled Task started using @Scheduled annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644141/spring-boot-stop-scheduled-task-started-using-scheduled-annotation) and [stop Spring Scheduled execution if it hangs after some fixed time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917757/stop-spring-scheduled-execution-if-it-hangs-after-some-fixed-time)